# Size of bit field compared to a char

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

So I know that

```
struct bit
{
    unsigned char a : 1;
}
```

will still take up a byte because of padding, my question is this:

```
struct bit
{
    unsigned char a : 1;
    ...
    unsigned char h : 1;
}
```

Will this struct take up the same size as a char? And if so, am I better off just using a `char` instead? I'm asking because I want to use bits as a key, but I'd rather avoid bitwise operations if possible.

Comment: Yes to same size. What do you mean by "better off"?

Comment: *Will this struct take up the same size as a char?* It depends on what's in between the two bit fields, the `...` part of your `struct`.

Comment: It's unclear what's the real problem you are trying to solve, what constraints are you operating under, and what are the pros and cons you are seeing with use of bit fields vs use of chars given the first two.

Comment: @Lundin:  I removed the C tag because the title explicitly said "C++".

Comment: Also make up your mind about programming language. I came here since I read the C tag, giving you a C answer. Now I see you have a C++ tag too. They are different, incompatible languages. C++, unlike C, actually has a useful bit-field type, std::bitset. Stop wasting peoples time.

Comment: in C, bitwise operations are the standard, portable way to store bit-sized chunks of information. If you're worried about readabilitiy or making errors through typoes, define a set of macros, e.g. I use SET_FLAG, CLEAR_FLAG and FLAG_IS_SET with obvious meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantees of anything when using bit-fields. That struct can have any size and any bit order. In fact `unsigned char` type for bit-fields is not even supported by the standard! Your code is already relying on non-standard extensions.

Forget about bit-fields, forget about `char`. You should use `uint8_t` and bitwise operators if you want predictable, portable code.

Comment: Or using a [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: @txtechhelp That's an extremely bad idea. If C++, use std::bitset.

Comment: I agree a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) would be another way to go, but why would using a `std::vector<bool>` be an _extremely_ bad idea? Maybe not the best choice given certain constraints (compiler/arch/optimizations), but it also depends on what the OP is _really_ trying to do (which isn't clear beyond size concerns and avoiding bit wise operations)..

Comment: @txtechhelp Because it will not give you a binary representation of anything, just an array of flags run-time allocated on the heap, with massive overhead.

Comment: @Lundin I'm reading the standard draft and can find no exceptions that would ban the use of `unsigned char`. Was this changed for the new standard? Otherwise, why are you saying that it is not supported?

Comment: @user2079303 C11 6.7.2.1/5: "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type." And then in Annex J (informative): "Common extensions" /--/ "J.5.8 Extended bit-field types
1 A bit-field may be declared with a type other than _Bool, unsigned int, or
signed int, with an appropriate maximum width"

Comment: @Lundin oh, I see the question is tagged as C as well. In C++ any integral and enumeration type is allowed, so whether OP's structure is supported would depend on which language they use.